# Expected RBRACE at line 2, col 23

Tags: css

I'm getting the above-mentioned error and I don't understand why it expects an `RBRACE` where it is calling for one, when there is one at the end.

```
.form-label.form-label-left:hover:after{ 
    content: Threshold: Delivery of product to the nearest ground-level entrance of home, business or apartment building

Room of Choice: Delivery of product to room of choice up or down one floor                  

Uncrate: Includes room of choice, plus removal or disposal of packing materials                 

Assembly: Includes Uncrate service plus 
assembly, Charges are based on estimated time of completion and are applied to the stop level, not individual pieces or boxes.";
    padding: 10px; 
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 6px;
    width: 130px;
    border: 4px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 6px 6px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px #666;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    white-space: normal;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The content line can't have multiple lines in it. That's also just not how to put content in your html.